# Getting "NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/util/ReflectionUtil"

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I am using below configuration in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

getting below error when spring boot starts:

> NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/util/ReflectionUtil

Comment: All three dependencies should use the same version.

Answer (score 0):

check out this [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.logging.logback.file-only-output) to configure log4j correctly

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2"
    modules {
        module("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging") {
            replacedBy("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2", "Use Log4j2 instead of Logback")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30587006)

Comment: @Rob I have edited & added the code to configure log4j